# Storing just images and videos in CloudFlare

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

I have a mobile app where I want to save and load a few sets of images/videos from Cloudflare.

Can I use Cloudflare to save images and videos and then access it in my mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

No. Cloudflare is just a CDN and DDoS mitigation service. It offers a lot of services, but it does not store content for you. You still need a place to store your static content like Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, Azure Blob Storage, Surge, or even just a plain old web server. You can use Cloudflare with one of these services to save bandwidth, decrease latency, and protect from DDoS attacks.

**UPDATE:** As CJackson234 mentioned, a static image and video hosting service exists now:

[Cloudflare Images](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-images/)

[Cloudflare Stream](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-stream/)

Comment: This is no longer accurate. Please see https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-images/

Comment: they also offer multiple storage options: https://developers.cloudflare.com/products/?product-group=Storage